# how inject vue-i18n's $t function to cy object(cypress global object)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress

I've installed vue-i18n in my vuejs application.

I need a way to use $t method in my cypress tests for assertions purpose.

I tried to write a custom function in `support/functions.js` and imported it in `support/index.js` through the following:

```
cy.$t = async (key) => {
    let t
    await cy.window().then(win => {
        t = win.Vue.$t(key)
    })
    return t
}
```

and used it in test file like this:

```
    cy.visit("/auth/login")
    cy.$t("general.login").then(val => cy.title().should("contain" , val))
```

as you can see: the function returns a Promise and I use "then" to get the value.
But I think this is a bad way.
so is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think this is "bad"?